# can sec:authorize from thymeleaf be used for multiple roles

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

So i have an element that i want to be accessible by both ADMIN and MODERATOR roles but not by regular users. I am using :

```
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/addFishToWater" 
  sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Admin</a>
```

For single role check it works properly but is there a way to check for any of the roles ADMIN and MODERATOR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/addFishToWater" 
  sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_MODERATOR')">Admin</a>
```

More info about other options can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html).

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you. Maybe I had a misspell or smt cuz I tried something like that.